# Casting Eloquent date to another date format doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

In my database I have a `some_date` column which is a `date` datatype in SQL Server.
The dates are stored as `YYYY-mm-dd` format in the database

I wanted the dates to appear as `dd-mm-YYYY` so I did the following in my model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'some_date' => 'date:d-m-Y',
];
```

But what it does is, it turns the date from `YYYY-mm-dd` to datetime with the same order:

`00:00:00 YYYY-mm-dd`

so instead of changing the date format, it leaves it the same and even adds the time, which doesn't exist, so it always displays it as `00:00:00`

Why?

Comment: this `00:00:00 YYYY-mm-dd` on DB or when receiving?

Comment: Only when receiving, on the DB it's simply `YYYY-mm-dd`

Comment: Do not direct when formatting a date. Add a variable to handle the formatted date. So you can do ```$formated_date = date("d-m-Y", $some_date);``` then call ```$formated_date```.

Comment: @Newbee it works, just with a bit of modification - since Eloquent returns the date as a string, I need to wrap `$some_date` in `strtotime()`. Btw I wanted to avoid converting in the PHP code because I thought that doing so via SQL would be faster, but I think I will just keep it in PHP code

Comment: @Stackerito, Then do it in your query when INSERTING data on your database. Ex ```VALUES (CONVERT(date,'02-08-2023',34))``` Where **34** is the standard formatted date by [SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/) for *dd-mm-YYYY*. When doing so, when date records is getting from your database table, it is already formatted.

Answer (score 0):

try modifying the accessor like this

```
public function getSomeDateAttribute($value){
    $formated_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value));
    return $formated_date;
}
```